Tailwind CSS Flexbox/Grid Layout Issues on iOS and macOS Safari using Next Js
I'm developing a website using Next.js and Tailwind CSS. While the layout works perfectly on most browsers, I'm encountering rendering issues specifically on iOS and macOS Safari. The layout is based on flexbox and grid, and the issue seems to be with text being cut off and layout elements not aligning correctly. Here's a screenshot of the issue:
enter image description here
My package.json:
{
  "name": "pcsonhos-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prepare": "husky"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^2.0.3",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.3",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.6.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.2.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-progress": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-radio-group": "^1.2.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.0.3",
    "@redux-devtools/extension": "^3.3.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.28.14",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^5.37.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.11",
    "flowbite": "^2.3.0",
    "flowbite-react": "^0.8.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "lucide-react": "^0.378.0",
    "next": "14.1.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-countup": "^6.5.3",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.2",
    "react-select": "^5.8.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.30.2",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "react-use": "^17.5.0",
    "sass": "^1.77.2",
    "sharp": "^0.33.4",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "sonner": "^1.5.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "tailwindcss-animated": "^1.1.0",
    "zod": "^3.23.8",
    "zustand": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.11",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.13",
    "@types/validator": "^13.11.10",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.4",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "prettier": "^3.3.2",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.6.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run build"
    }
  }
}

My component

      {
        lottery.status === "ACTIVE"
        &&
        <section className="w-11/12 mx-auto lg:w-8/12 mb-5 ">
          <LotteryCart lottery={lottery} />
        </section>
      }


      <section className="mx-auto w-11/12 lg:w-8/12 lg:my-8 my-4">
        <Ranking />
        <div className=" md:hidden">
          <AwardTitles />
        </div>
        <WinnersVideos />
        <div className="w-full">
          <div className="mb-8 flex justify-center">
            <div className="mb-8 mt-4 cursor-pointer rounded-3xl p-1 shadow-lg ">
              <h3 className="rounded-3xl px-3 text-center text-base font-medium sm:text-2xl">
                 Extração loteria federal 
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>

          <h2 className="mb-8 text-center text-2xl font-bold lg:text-3xl">
            Confira os detalhes da premiação:
          </h2>
          <div className="">
            <div className="border-1 rounded-lg border border-solid border-slate-500 p-4">
              <div className=" overflow-y-auto">
                {lottery.description
                  .split("\n")
                  .map((text: string, index: number) => (
                    <p className="lg:text-lg" key={index}>
                      {text}
                    </p>
                  ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>

        <ProductImages />


        <div className="flex mt-8 gap-3 mb-2">
          <div className=" p-3 border-4 rounded-full border-lime-500 bg-slate-100/15 shadow-lg shadow-lime-500/50 ">
            <ReceiptText className="text-lime-500" />
          </div>
          <div className=" p-3 border-4 rounded-full border-lime-500 bg-slate-100/15 shadow-lg shadow-lime-500/50 ">
            <Trophy className="text-lime-500" />
          </div>

        </div>
        <p className="mb-4 mt-0 text-2xl font-bold lg:text-4xl">
          Mais informações
        </p>
        <p className="font-medium text-gray-500 lg:text-xl">
          São <strong>10 cotas premiadas</strong> de{" "}
          <strong>500 reais cada</strong>: 121212, 343434, 565656, 787878,
          909090, 012345, 678901, 147369, 741963 e 123580.
        </p>
        <Accordion
          type="single"
          collapsible
          className="mt-10 transition-all duration-300 ease-linear"
        >
          <AccordionItem value="item-1">
            <AccordionTrigger className="text-xl">Regulamento</AccordionTrigger>
            <AccordionContent>
              <article className="mt-2 text-base font-normal border border-slate-500 rounded-lg p-3">
                {lottery.regulation.split("\n").map((paragraph, index) => (
                  <p key={index}>{paragraph}</p>
                ))}
              </article>
            </AccordionContent>
          </AccordionItem>
        </Accordion>



        <FaqQuestions />
        <Faq />
        <br />
      </section>



I am expecting to be like this
enter image description here

Your code does not help; it could be anything.
You can try to make a reproducible example at https://play.tailwindcss.com/

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
